# Javascript Keydown Event Handler Not Working Correctly

Tags: javascript, keydown

I would like the keydown event to trigger each audio clip it is assigned to within its respective button on this drum machine but for some reason only the active button seems to work.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<body>
  
  <div id='drum-machine' class='row justify-content-between'>
    
    <div id='display-1' class='cols-6'>
      <div class='row'>
        <button id='heater1' class='drum-pad'>Q
          <audio id='Q' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3'></audio>           </button>
        <button id='heater2' class='drum-pad'>W
          <audio id='W' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>  
        </button>
        <button id='heater3' class='drum-pad'>E
          <audio id='E' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <button id='heater4' class='drum-pad'>A
          <audio id='A' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>  
        </button>
        <button id='clap' class='drum-pad'>S
          <audio id='S' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>  
        </button>
        <button id='OHH' class='drum-pad'>D
          <audio id='D' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>  
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <button id='KHH' class='drum-pad'>Z
          <audio id='Z' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3'></audio>  
        </button>
        <button id='kick' class='drum-pad'>X
          <audio id='X' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>  
        </button>
        <button id='CHH' class='drum-pad'>C
          <audio id='C' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>  
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var pad = document.getElementsByClassName('drum-pad');

for(let i = 0; i < pad.length; i++){
  pad[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    if (pad[i].children[0].id.charCodeAt() == event.keyCode){
     pad[i].children[0].play();
     pad[i].classList.toggle('active');
    }
  })  
};
```

Comment: Why not handle keydown at the document level?  The way you have it, only the pad with keyboard focus will receive the keydown event.  I assume that's not what you're intending.  You should handle key events with a single listener on the document, that plays the sound for the appropriate pad depending on which key was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pads = document.getElementsByClassName('drum-pad');


document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  for(let i = 0; i < pads.length; i++) {
    pad = pads[i];
    if(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == pad.innerText) {
      pad.children[0].play();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id='drum-machine' class='row justify-content-between'>
    
    <div id='display-1' class='cols-6'>
      <div class='row'>
        <button id='heater1' class='drum-pad'>Q
          <audio id='Q' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3'></audio>           </button>
        <button id='heater2' class='drum-pad'>W
          <audio id='W' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>  
        </button>
        <button id='heater3' class='drum-pad'>E
          <audio id='E' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <button id='heater4' class='drum-pad'>A
          <audio id='A' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>  
        </button>
        <button id='clap' class='drum-pad'>S
          <audio id='S' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>  
        </button>
        <button id='OHH' class='drum-pad'>D
          <audio id='D' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>  
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <button id='KHH' class='drum-pad'>Z
          <audio id='Z' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3'></audio>  
        </button>
        <button id='kick' class='drum-pad'>X
          <audio id='X' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>  
        </button>
        <button id='CHH' class='drum-pad'>C
          <audio id='C' class='clip' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>  
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You just need to check if the character pressed by the keyboard is the same as a character in one of the buttons then play said sound. Also, you need to listen for keydown events on the whole document, not just a pad element. Let me know if you have any questions or require any clarification.

Comment: That works perfectly!  Thank you all.  I didn't think about setting it up at the document level.  

One other small question I have however is about trying to toggle the active class also.  It seems simple but I can't get it to work.  

Thanks again.

CSS
```
.drum-pad:active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

JS
```

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  for (let i = 0; i < pad.length; i++){
    if(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == pad[i].innerText){
      pad[i].classList.toggle('active');
      pad[i].children[0].play();
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: In you css don't say `.drum-pad:active` say `.active` to specify what to do with the active class. Also, I would really appreciate it if you could accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: that got it working thank you.  How do I go about accepting your answer?  I can't find anything like that on the page.

Comment: There's a check mark below the upvote and downvote button, thank you very much